# Filtering Data by Month and Day with Pasted Year

Tags: r, dplyr, as.date

I am getting the following error when I run my data through my script:

Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = SampleDate >= as.Date(paste(year(SampleDate), 3, 15, sep = "-"))`.
Caused by error in `charToDate()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

My code previously did not have this error prior to the update to Funny Looking Kid. (Is anyone else hating this recent update?) It is a filter that selects a range of dates based on month and day and then pastes the associated year back in to create a date with month, day, and year. Here, my range of dates is 15 March through 15 September:

```
S1 <- S1 %>%
  mutate(
    year=year(SampleDate), # extract parts
    month=month(SampleDate),
    day=day(SampleDate)
  )

S1 <-S1 %>%
  filter(SampleDate >= as.Date(paste(year(SampleDate), 03, 15, sep = "-")),
         SampleDate <= as.Date(paste(year(SampleDate), 09, 15, sep = "-")))
```

I cannot share my data file, but all dates are in Date class and are formatted as 2013-05-07 (YMD)

I have tried resolving this using the anytime package:

```
S1 <-S1 %>%
  filter(SampleDate >= as.Date(paste(year(anydate(SampleDate)), 03, 15, sep = "-")),
         SampleDate <= as.Date(paste(year(anydate(SampleDate)), 09, 15, sep = "-")))
```

and by reformatting in YMD order:

```
S1 <-S1 %>%
  filter(SampleDate >= as.Date(paste(year(SampleDate), sep = "-", 03, 15)),
         SampleDate <= as.Date(paste(year(SampleDate), sep = "-", 09, 15)))
```

I get the same error no matter what I try. I would really appreciate any work around anyone can offer!

Comment: If you performed an update to R, are you sure all of the libraries are installed and updated?  Or there say there is an issue with one of your values of SampleDate.  Hard to say without seeing a sample of "SampleDate"

Comment: @Dave2e I just updated all of my packages and I get the same error. Here is a small sample df: df <- data.frame(SampleDate = c('3/19/2013',

                                '12/6/2011',

                                '6/15/2015',

                                '4/17/2013',

                                '4/5/2011',

                                '2/21/2013'),  Result = c(0.6,

                            0.4,

                            0.3,

                            0.3,

                            0.1,

                            0.3)

Comment: I also tried creating a new column that stores the date value of SampleDate and filters on that, but get the same chartodate error:                                                                                                                                             
df <- df |> mutate(Date2=mdy(SampleDate))

df <- df %>%

  filter(Date2 >= as.Date(paste(year(Date2), 03, 15, sep = "-")),

         Date2 <= as.Date(paste(year(Date2), 09, 15, sep = "-")))

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce your issue, maybe the `year()` function is the issue.
Here is a straightforward approach, converting the sample date into a Date with base R:

```
df <- data.frame(SampleDate = c('3/19/2013', '12/6/2011', '6/15/2015', '4/17/2013', '4/5/2011', '2/21/2013'), 
                 Result = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3))
    

df$SampleDate <- as.Date(df$SampleDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
df$year <- format(df$SampleDate, "%Y")

library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(SampleDate >= as.Date(paste(year, 03, 15, sep = "-")), SampleDate <=as.Date(paste(year, 09, 15, sep = "-")))
```